# How save element multiple in dictionary?

Tags: django, python-3.x

Suppose I have a model like this:

```
class Post(model.Model)
   name = model.CharField(max_lenght)
   description= model.CharField()
```

and I have this dictionary

```
d = {'name':'jerry', 'description':'all}
```

For save dict:

```
p = Post(**d)
p.save()
```

But IF I have this dict:

```
d = {'name':'jerry', 'description':'all, 'name1': 'lucy', 'description1': 'tr'}
```

Can I save element in Post:

```
Name    Description
jerry     all
lucy      tr
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing some quotes... This being said, why would you store the `name` inside `name1` instead of making a list of valid dictionnaries ?

Comment: And what if one of your fields is for example `name1`? Then this would result in ambiguity. Usually it is better to solve this problem for a *list* of *dictionaries*, each with their real names.

Comment: so list of dictionaries {'name':['jerry', 'luc'], 'description'['add','fil']}